# How to center an absolutely positioned div within IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, internet-explorer-7

**UPDATED PROVIDING CONTEXT FOR THE LAYOUT**

I have a relatively simple structure for my page.  The page is composed of two div's both absolutely positioned.  One is centered within the other.[image]

```
<div id="protocol_index_body_wrapper">
    <div id="protocol_index_body">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which has the corresponding CSS:

```
#protocol_index_body_wrapper {
    background: url("/images/stripe.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
#protocol_index_body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

The expected behavior is seen in the image above.  This behavior is present in IE8, Firefox, and Chrome.  However, in IE7 the div which should be centered is flush against the left side.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `text-align: center;` to `#protocol_index_body`

Comment: Try setting a width of 100% on the body_wrapper div.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're giving the inner div an absolute position. If you want it centered inside an already absolute positioned element then you don't need it to be absolute.

Comment: I think I've fixed it to what you need. I looked at what it looked like from the initial code you had in FF and went from there. Take a look at my code below.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#protocol_index_body {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or ...

```
#protocol_index_body {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -25px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Works but only because you used a fixed margin. Needs to stay in the center of the screen regardless of its size.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the parent div to have a fluid width (which would be a little silly when you're setting the child div's width), why not just set the parent div's width and add `margin:0 auto`?

Comment: The parent div is a full width background on the child div.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I played around with it and this works identical in FF, Opera and IE7:

```
#protocol_index_body_wrapper {
  background-color:black;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#protocol_index_body {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The height and width being set messes with the layout of the screen.  See updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
autoCenterAlign = function() {

    var bodyWidth = $("body").innerWidth();
    var protocolWidth = $("#protocol_index_body").innerWidth();
    if(protocolWidth < bodyWidth) {

        $("#protocol_index_body").css("left",((bodyWidth-protocolWidth)/2)+"px");

    }

}

window.onload = autoCenterAlign;
window.onresize = autoCenterAlign;
jQuery(window).load(function () { 

    autoCenterAlign()

});
```

Answer (score -1):

`text-align:center` to the wrapper, or  `<div align=center>` (ugly, I know, but works)

or with JS:

```
document.getElementById("protocol_index_body_wrapper").style.marginRight = (document.body.clientWidth - 50)/2_+"px"
```

works only on IE6+.