# CSS aligning images horizontally

Tags: css

I am new to css and I am trying to align my images horziontally inside a div element.

I tried float and display : inline but still they are aligning vertically .

```
#maincontainer {
   left : 50px;
 top : 80px;
 width : 300px;
 height : 100px;
 border : solid 2px #0f0f0f;
 position : absolute;
 overflow : scroll;

 }

 #maincontainer img {
    top : 10px;
    left : 10px;
    width : 80px;
    height : 80px;
    padding : 10px;
    position :relative; 
    float : left; 
   }
```

Please help and tell me if I am wrong smwhere.

Comment: try this
[How to center an absolutely positioned div within IE7?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218582/how-to-center-an-absolutely-positioned-div-within-ie7/13467536#13467536

Answer (score 17):

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

Answer (score 8):

horizontally aligned

html

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <img />
</div>
```

css

```
 #maincontainer {
     width : 300px;
     height : 100px;
     border : solid 2px #0f0f0f;
     }
     #maincontainer img {
        width : 80px;
        height : 80px;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
        background:red;
    }​
```

vertically and horizontally aligned

html

```
 <div id="maincontainer">
        <div><img /></div>
    </div> ​
```

css

```
 #maincontainer {
     width : 300px;
     height : 100px;
     border : solid 2px #0f0f0f;
     display:table;
     }
     #maincontainer div img {
        width : 80px;
        height : 80px;
        background:red;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #maincontainer div{
     display:table-cell;
       text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }​
```

just remove background:red from img

Answer (score 4):

As long as the parent container is wide enough for the images, they will naturally sit side-by-side. When the row of images becomes too wide for the container, the images will start to wrap down to a new line of text.

Also, white space (space, tab, and newline characters) will be rendered as a text space between two images. To prevent this, make sure there are no white space characters between the `IMG` tags.

Images can be forced to overflow the parent container's width by setting the CSS `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element. This can cause undesired effects if the container gets too narrow, but can also be used to create a horizontal scrollbar by adding `overflow: auto;` to the containing element.

Finally, image tags can have a `vertical-align` CSS property. By default it is `vertical-align: baseline;`. This creates a few pixels of white space beneath the image. You can counter this by setting `vertical-align: top;` for the image in the CSS.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwv7n/) for some examples with pictures.

Comment: Hey thank you this fiddle solved my problem. The white-space : nowrap part.

Answer (score 1):

If your div is wide enough to contain all your images in one row, then you can simply try something like this :

```
#maincontainer img {
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

see it live: http://tinkerbin.com/mIBcXNcS
That's the basic code, but it can vary depending on your html code....

Answer (score 0):

Hi now Change  to your position according to this

Now define your **parent** position `relative` and give to child `absolute`

```
#maincontainer {
 position : relative;
 }

 #maincontainer img {
    position :absolute; 
   }
```

### -----

**I think u want to this**

now change some `properties` of your `css`

and now **add** the `margin-top` and `margin-left`  **remove** `top` or `left` in **your parent** `id maincontainer`

as like **this**

```
#maincontainer {
 width : 300px;
 height : 100px;
  margin-top:80px;
  margin-left:50px;
 border : solid 2px #0f0f0f;
 position : relative;
 overflow : scroll;

 }

 #maincontainer img {
    top : 10px;
    left : 10px;
    width : 80px;
    height : 80px;
    padding : 10px;
    position :absolute; 
  vertical-align:top;
   }
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/LXo1jbd9)***

Comment: This is unnecessary when floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to apply `display:block;` to the IMG element for floats to work. inline elements cannot be floated.
2. Alternatively, define IMG as `display:inline-block;`, but be aware that this is not supported by older browsers
3. As a side note, try to avoid as much as you can from defining height in CSS (or use min-height). Unlike the width, the height of many elements, especially a main container, should be flexible.